# rsync options to exclude deletes

Tags: backup, shell, rsync

I backup my files from my desktop to my FreeNAS box with rsync. Here is the command I use:

```
rsync.exe  -v -rlt -z --chmod=a=rw,Da+x --delete --exclude="Torrents/Downloads" --exclude="Torrents/Watch" "/cygdrive/D/Storage/" "garni::Storage/"
```

so this ignores both directories "Torrents/Downloads" and "Torrents/Watch", so it wont delete them on the remote side. it works fine.

This isnt what iam trying to do. I want to exclude the deletes from the remote side but still send any files from local to remote. My current parameters are completely excluding them. How can I exclude the deletes to the server, but still include files from local to server?

Answer (score 1):

All the delete-related options apply to everything being sync'ed, you can't change them for specific directories.

You can do what you want by running two rsyncs. First use your existing command to backup everything except `Torrents/Downloads` and `Torrents/Watch` with deletion. Then backup just the `Torrents/Watch` and `Torrents/Downloads` directories, but without the `--delete` option.